# How can I get npm start at a different directory?

Tags: node.js

I usually `cd` into the app directory and then run `npm start`.

It is my feeling that there ought to be some way to run `npm start` with a path parameter. But, the [npm start documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start) contains no such feature.

I tried myself only to find `npm start ./myapp` does not work. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 817):

This one-liner should work:

```
npm start --prefix path/to/your/app
```

[Corresponding doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/config#prefix)

Comment: Not working. Trying to find package.json in current directory.

Comment: @ShashwatKumar did you ever find a working way of doing this?

Comment: @Juicy I honestly don't remember if I could make it work or not.

Comment: I just tested to run this command in a folder having a `package.json` as well, and npm correctly followed the `path/to/your/app` to find the right `package.json`. Which version of npm are you using?

Comment: Running on macOS10.14.x with node 10.x and npm 6.9.0 the one-liner worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Docs for `--prefix` here: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#prefix

Answer (score 212):

Below Command  where `project` is a folder which contains `package.json` file

```
npm run --prefix project ${COMMAND}
```

is working as well. 
Useful in Docker based applications.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer to me, as it documents that you need to pass the command *after* the prefix flag and the path. The example of "npm start --prefix path/to/your/app" is an edge case due to the way that npm lets you use "npm start" or "npm test" as a short hand for "npm run start/test". That example doesn't help if someone needs to run a command other than start or test.

Comment: Can you tell me, suppose `server.js` is not in the `root` folder, how can I map to the `server.js` path to root `package.json` file, so that when I run command from `root` folder, like `npm start` it will execute `server.js` no matter where it is located?

Comment: To clarify, should this look like `npm run --prefix /path/to/project ${start}` or `npm run --prefix /path/to/project start` ?

Comment: Please select option B

Answer (score 31):

I came here from google so it might be relevant to others:
for `yarn` you could use:

```
yarn --cwd /path/to/your/app run start
```

Answer (score 24):

`npm start --prefix path/to/your/app`

& inside package.json add the following script

```
"scripts": {
   "preinstall":"cd $(pwd)"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the preinstall script does?

Comment: This is not cross-platform. It only works on Unix and not on odd-balls like Windows.

Answer (score 20):

This one-liner should work too:

```
(cd /path/to/your/app && npm start)
```

Note that the current directory will be changed to /path/to/your/app after executing this command. To preserve the working directory:

```
(cd /path/to/your/app && npm start && cd -)
```

I used this solution because a program configuration file I was editing back then didn't support specifying command line arguments.

Comment: Please when using "-1" button, add a comment so visitors have a clue "why it's not ok"...

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I believe that it's downvoted because of the side effects. The solution is not pure, it changes the current directory.

Comment: This is actually a very common solution, the only improvement that would be done is to add parenthesis to avoid mentioned side effects. However solutions above are better in my opition, as they purely rely on NPM.

Comment: You can add `cd -` on the end to remove the side effect.

Comment: @babca unless `npm start` fails... you need to break that into multiple statements

Comment: I also didn't downvote, but the question specifically says that the questioner is using cd and then running npm, but is looking for a way to provide a path parameter.  So this very much does not answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

Per this [npm issue list](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9627), one work around could be done through npm config

```
name: 'foo'
config: { path: "baz" },
scripts: { start: "node ./$npm_package_config_path" }
```

Under windows, the `scripts` could be `{ start: "node ./%npm_package_config_path%" }`

Then run the command line as below

```
npm start --foo:path=myapp
```

Comment: what script could do for the downloaded packages? Suppose I want to access js file from downloaded npm package