# Publish npm, and after installation on other PC have error

Tags: node.js, npm-install, npm-publish

and then install it on other pc to check. Bu after install package and it depencies i have error when try to start it

```
pm ERR! Linux 4.10.0-38-generic
npm ERR! argv "/home/pavlo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/node" "/home/pavlo/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.4/bin/npm" "start" "storjboard"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /home/pavlo/Desktop/test/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pavlo/Desktop/test/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pavlo/Desktop/test/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/pavlo/Desktop/test/npm-debug.log
```

Problem it that i have to clone package.json from git , how i can publish correctly with package.json?

Note: command start inside package.json scripts

My json for publish:

```
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.3",
  "description": "Name",
  "main": "script.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "request": "^2.83.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "start": "node node_modules/module/script.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/me/module"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "somewords"
  ],
  "author": "me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/me/module/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/me/module#readme"
}
```

Error (WARN) when installing module on other PC

```
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/pavlo/Desktop/test/package.json'
npm WARN test No description
npm WARN test No repository field.
npm WARN test No README data
npm WARN test No license field.
```

But in `test/node_modules/module/(here there are everything)` readme, json and script

Comment: It seems you're not launching your start script from your module directory.

Comment: yes, but it is possible  to launch not from module dir this? In module dir json present

Comment: I go to dir test , there `npm install <module>` and there try to run `npm start <module>` But json is in dir `test/node_modules/module`

Comment: Yes it's possible but you have to change your start script to point to the module (something like _node node_modules/yourmodule/script.js_).

Comment: changes but the same updated json in question, maybe need somehow path to json file

Comment: No I mean the start script in the package_json file from where you launch the command (test). Or maybe you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772105/5156280).

Comment: `"start": "node node_modules/module/script.js"`

Comment: But the error the same module can't find json in test dir, but it have to look in node_module/module/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to start your module from another directory, you can do it like this:

In your module *package.json*

```
{
  "name": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node script.js"
  }
}
```

from the test directory (as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772105/5156280) answer suggest):

```
npm start --prefix node_modules/module/
```

Alternately, you can start your module by creating a package.json file in your test directory and adding a script:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/module/script.js"
  }
}
```

Usally *npm* packages are placed in node_modules directory because those modules are supposed to be used as dependencies, not directly.

It depends on the purpose of your application, but maybe you might be interested in doing a post-install script or installing it globally.

[npm doc](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally#installing-npm-packages-locally) for packages installation.