# How can I fix problem in run a react project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

How can I fix this problem in npm start?

```
PS D:\__Learning-&-Practicing\Programing\Web\React-JS\React-JS-App-1> cd react-js-app-1
PS D:\__Learning-&-Practicing\Programing\Web\React-JS\React-JS-App-1\react-js-app-1> npm start


Error: Cannot find module 'D:\react-scripts\bin\react-scripts.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:797:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:27)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

This does not start from current location.

Comment: Can you also post your package.json?

Comment: See if this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172442/how-to-npm-start-at-a-different-directory