# Can I run `npm run build` outside the client directory of a react project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

my project consists of a react frontend and an express backend. It has the following hierarchy:

project\

- package.json
- server.js
- node_modules\
- client\

  - package.json
  - src\
  - public\
  - node_modules\

I know that running `npm run build` inside the `client` folder will run `react-scripts build` (as stated in its `package.json`) that will bundle all the client folder contents for deployment.

I have several questions regarding this:

- how do i do bundling like using `react-scripts start` but in the `project` folder?
- is it ideal to have duplicates of `package.json` and `node_modules`, one for `client` and one for `project` folder?

Comment: Could you be more specific with a single question? Yes you can define a build script in the root package file, for example.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172442/how-can-i-get-npm-start-at-a-different-directory