# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\username\Documents\My Music'

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am trying to run this react app: https://github.com/JackHeTech/multiplayer-chess-game

It works when I download the repo and do npm install and then npm start.

But when I try to make the project myself using create-react-app with these steps:

```
npx create-react-app frontend
*copy the required files from repo to frontend folder*
npm install <p1> <p2> ...
npm start
```

That doesn't work and shows these errors:

```
Compiling...
C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\chess_server\frontend\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\username\Documents\My Music'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\My Music'
}
PS C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\chess_server\frontend>
```

Why is it pointing to 'C:\Users\username\Documents\My Music'?  I have not used that path anywhere in my files.

Basically I am trying to recreate the project from the repo on my own. But it's giving me the error given above.

Comment: Open an issue on the GitHub repo from which you got the code.

Comment: Its a compilation error, can you search your code for `My Music`

Comment: @kiranvj There's no "My Music" in my code. I don't know how My music is related to the project.

Comment: Can you search in all folders including `node_modules` . Editors will not search `node_modules` by default.

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68302676/updated-create-react-app-is-trying-to-find-my-videos

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same error, and the problem was that i was importing something without actually installing the npm package. In my case, it was react-router-dom. Double check that you've actually installed all your dependencies that you've used in your code with `npm install --save <your dependency>`

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed odd that it references my music. Did try `npm install` inside the project folder? If so, try deleting `package.json` and running `npm install` again.

**EDIT**
I was also plagued by this error, and after trying all the other answers, magically found the following solution:

Delete `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder, then run `npm install` again.

If that doesn't work, try running these in order:

```
npm install
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g npm
npm install
```

and then re-deleting the above files and re-running `npm install`.

Worked for me!

Comment: Thanks for replying! I have tried that. It still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Only do this when you don't see a build folder after pushing to GitHub again

it will work if you run: npm run build
-- This should create a build folder

Before you run: npm run deploy

Answer (score -3):

Please remove the space between your folder name "My Music" to either "My_Music" or "My-Music" or "MyMusic" or whatever you like (but **WITHOUT SPACE**).
The issue here is as it detects space it will try to find path till My only and consider other members as attributes may be (I am not quite sure )

It does not convert the path with encoding tahts the issue.

NOTE: Keep the practice to not add space in name of folder.

Comment: Hi Thanks! But afaik I never used that path anywhere. Can you please tell me how can I find that error in my code?

Comment: @Het what is your project path? is it -::C:\Users\username\Documents\Projects\chess_server\frontend 

OR -
C:\Users\username\Documents\My Music?

Comment: the former one.

Comment: Can you check the system environment variable path?

Comment: and can you check this once?   https://stackoverflow.com/a/41772105/2677551