# zsh: permission denied when running from outside directory

Tags: linux, npm, zsh, manjaro

I have a package.json at:

```
/home/user/dev/project/package.json
```

If I navigate to this location:

```
cd /home/user/dev/project
```

Then run a command:

```
npm run compile
```

It works and there are no errors.

However, if I try to run the command like this

```
/home/user/dev/project/ npm run compile
```

I get a message:

```
zsh: permission denied: /home/user/dev/project/
```

Why is this happening? I have not changed the user I'm logged in as.

Comment: Because `/home/user...` is a folder, and you try to execute a folder, and that's not possible. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172442/how-can-i-get-npm-start-at-a-different-directory on how to do this correctly.

Comment: In the second case, you are trying to run a program named `/home/user/dev/project` with the arguments `npm`, `run` and `compile`. This does not make sense. Note that the first word of a statement is the program to be executed, and the following words are the arguments of that programm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first word of a command is the name of the program to run. The directory is not an executable program, so you get that error.

If you want to refer to a file in another directory, put the directory name in the filename:

```
npm run compile /home/user/dev/project
```

Comment: Thank you! But a minor correction, in my case the command would be:

npm run compile /home/user/dev/project


Because the compile is refering to a script inside of package.json.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused and thought `compile` was the filename to run.

Comment: Another thing, if I run the command as `npm run compile /home/user/dev/project`it does work but I have an error with compilation itself:

`Could not resolve the path '/home/user/dev/project' with the extension '.ts', 'tsx'...`
I don't know why this happens, but if I run the command as:

`npm run compile --prefix /home/user/dev/project`

It does not give the error. So I would use that one instead.

Comment: This seems to be more about how to use `npm` properly.