# Next JS build error, when triggered via webhook

Tags: node.js, next.js, environment-variables, webhooks

[error log, i get after the build fails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztbk0.png)

Hello,

I have a problem, where build processes fail, explicitely when triggered through a webhook in a NextJS api route.

**Important: Manually run builds via "npm run build" work just fine and the same webhook (Contentful) is effortlessly calling builds in another project using the same exact code**:

My api file in Next JS (/pages/api/my-path-name.js):
Node version: v18.15.0
Next JS version: 13.4.7

```
const { exec } = require('child_process')

// the same code in my express app is correctly running the build with no errors (app.post('/hook', (req, res) => ...)
export default function hook(req, res) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        res.status(405).send({ message: 'Only POST requests allowed' })
        return
    }
    
    console.log("post received")

    // Run npm run build command
    const buildProcess = exec('npm run build');

    // Log the output of the build process
    buildProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data);
    });

    // Log any errors that occur during the build process
    buildProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(data);
    });

    // Execute a callback when the build process is complete
    buildProcess.on('close', (code) => {
        if (code === 0) {
            console.log('Build process completed successfully.');
            res.status = 200
            res.send('success')
            return
        } else {
            console.error(`Build process exited with code ${code}.`);
            res.status = 405
            res.end()
            return
        }
    });

    res.status = 405
    res.end()
    return
}
```

Note, that the webhook itself is working fine and Contentful is giving me only status 200 success logs. The  `exec('npm run ubild')` is in fact getting called, but is exiting with error code 1, saying the error in the attached image.

Since I can't find any results when searching for this problem, I have no clue what to do.

My guess is, that the "npm run build" command is beeing executed from a wrong place. Therefore I tried running it from the root directory `exec('npm run --prefix ../../ build')` as explained here [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172442/how-can-i-get-npm-start-at-a-different-directory). But that didn't help either, as it tried running it from 2 directories down from the root, proofing the actual directory to be just right.

**Edit:
In development mode, i get a "non-standard NODE_ENV" warning for some reason. The trouble is, I haven't set a NODE_ENV anywhere. I can't even find "NODE_ENV" in my entire folder structure.**
`- warn You are using a non-standard "NODE_ENV" value in your environment. This creates inconsistencies in the project and is strongly advised against. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/non-standard-node-env`

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "smina-shop",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^15.17.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.5.0",
    "contentful": "^10.4.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "formidable": "^3.5.1",
    "friendly-challenge": "^0.9.13",
    "next": "12.2.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.4",
    "postcss": "8.4.27",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "swiper": "^8.4.7",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  }
}
```

The next.config:

```
/**
 * @type {import('next').NextConfig}
 */
const nextConfig = {
    // output: 'export',
    // Optional: Add a trailing slash to all paths `/about` -> `/about/`
    // trailingSlash: true,
    // Optional: Change the output directory `out` -> `dist`
    // distDir: '',
    assetPrefix: './'
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Let me know, if you need any further information.
Any help would be well appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: would it be possible for you could provide the `package.json` as well as the `next.config.js` file?

Comment: done! Thanks for answering. Btw, I also tried adding a generateBuildId function to the next.config as explained here: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/generateBuildId